# R Selenium unable to findElement return Error Selenium message:Unable to locate element

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am webscraping information from this "https://lsf.uni-heidelberg.de/qisserver/rds?state=change&type=6&moduleParameter=personalSelect&nextdir=change&next=SearchSelect.vm&target=personSearch&subdir=person&init=y&source=state%3Dchange%26type%3D5%26moduleParameter%3DpersonSearch%26nextdir%3Dchange%26next%3Dsearch.vm%26subdir%3Dperson%26menuid%3Dsearch%26_form%3Ddisplay%26topitem%3Dmembers%26subitem%3D%26field%3DNachname&targetfield=Nachname&_form=display" .
I would like to search each individual to collect email addresses. I am doing the following but I can't find a way to submit the search button.

```
#url
uni<-"https://lsf.uni-heidelberg.de/qisserver/rds?state=change&type=6&moduleParameter=personalSelect&nextdir=change&next=SearchSelect.vm&target=personSearch&subdir=person&init=y&source=state%3Dchange%26type%3D5%26moduleParameter%3DpersonSearch%26nextdir%3Dchange%26next%3Dsearch.vm%26subdir%3Dperson%26menuid%3Dsearch%26_form%3Ddisplay%26topitem%3Dmembers%26subitem%3D%26field%3DNachname&targetfield=Nachname&_form=display"

#people's name
r<-read_html(uni)
name <- r %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_text()
name<-name[40:length(name)]
name<-gsub("\n","",name ,fixed = T)
name<-gsub("\t","",name ,fixed = T)

#people's first link
link <- r %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
html_attrs() %>%
  as.character()
link<-link[40:length(link)]
link<-str_split(link, '"')
link<-sapply(link, "[", 6)


#create a loop: with R selenium, click on search for each link and get emails which are in the next page

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
#remDr$navigate("https://ki.se/en/research/professors-at-ki")

for (i in 1:lenght(link)) {
  i=1
 #r<- read_html(link[i])
 remDr$navigate(link[i])
 webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*+[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "abstand_search", " " ))]//font//input')
 
 webElem$clickElement()
 
#here i get the error
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers. I would go with faster and more intuitive, on reading, css selectors to gather the links:

```
library(rvest)

links <- read_html('https://lsf.uni-heidelberg.de/qisserver/rds?state=change&type=6&moduleParameter=personalSelect&nextdir=change&next=SearchSelect.vm&target=personSearch&subdir=person&init=y&source=state%3Dchange%26type%3D5%26moduleParameter%3DpersonSearch%26nextdir%3Dchange%26next%3Dsearch.vm%26subdir%3Dperson%26menuid%3Dsearch%26_form%3Ddisplay%26topitem%3Dmembers%26subitem%3D%26field%3DNachname&targetfield=Nachname&_form=display') %>% 
  html_nodes('.regular[name]') %>% 
  html_attr('href')
```

Then, I would use same strategy to target the search button:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '.abstand_search + [value="Suche starten"]')  # this matches for the element which is interactable
```

Finally, I would pick up name and email from destination page

```
name <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '.regular')
email <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '[href*=mail]') # could also take 2nd match for .regular
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr. I get this error ```Selenium message:Unable to locate element: .regular
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-CHTJ7C0D', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown```

Comment: can you share the url from the automated webpage at that point please? When error occurs.

Comment: Sure, here it is \url{https://lsf.uni-heidelberg.de/qisserver/rds;jsessionid=E36BF14654B9C3F57A8112C46B3F0B74.histom17TCC?state=change&type=5&moduleParameter=personSearch&nextdir=change&next=search.vm&subdir=person&menuid=search&_form=display&topitem=members&subitem=&field=Nachname&personal.pid=25744&idcol=personal.pid&idval=25744&purge=n&getglobal=n&text=Abaci%2C+Ali++Dr.+med.} thank you

Comment: Oh so page looks different for you. You can swop .regular with `#personal\.nachname` I didn't end up on that page. That page doesn't have email on.

Comment: You should be starting [here](https://lsf.uni-heidelberg.de/qisserver/rds?state=change&type=6&moduleParameter=personalSelect&nextdir=change&next=SearchSelect.vm&target=personSearch&subdir=person&init=y&source=state%3Dchange%26type%3D5%26moduleParameter%3DpersonSearch%26nextdir%3Dchange%26next%3Dsearch.vm%26subdir%3Dperson%26menuid%3Dsearch%26_form%3Ddisplay%26topitem%3Dmembers%26subitem%3D%26field%3DNachname&targetfield=Nachname&_form=display) - note that if you do this in ordinary browser you may get sent direct to an individual's link cached rather than the list of all staff

Comment: In the loop over retrieved hrefs you would first then go to [this](https://lsf.uni-heidelberg.de/qisserver/rds;jsessionid=4AF85F7F96867277DA068E8BA37BAD67.histom18TCA?state=change&type=5&moduleParameter=personSearch&nextdir=change&next=search.vm&subdir=person&menuid=search&_form=display&topitem=members&subitem=&field=Nachname&personal.pid=25744&idcol=personal.pid&idval=25744&purge=n&getglobal=n&text=Abaci%2C+Ali++Dr.+med.) , on that page click `Suche starten` and then you are on the right page to extract the name and email using the css selectors I gave in my answer; not on the page before.

Comment: I am now on the right page, but when I run name and email I get the following ```  "remoteDriver fields"
$remoteServerAddr
[1] "localhost"

$port
[1] 4545

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$javascript
[1] TRUE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$extraCapabilities
list()

[1] "webElement fields"
$elementId
[1] "80f8231c-edf3-44a4-bfc1-48abe88d8394" ``` for name and email. Following #personal\.nachname instead I get an error ```Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'personal\." ```

Comment: When on the right page please use selectors as per my answer. Not from the comments.

Comment: Did you try with selectors as per my answer?

Comment: Yep, but was giving me the error I reported above. Sincerly I don't understand why, I tried also different combinations. Further, I tried different css and xpath using the google developers selector that returns different css or xpath but was still not working

Comment: The error above mentions a selector that is not in my answer which is why I am confused. It mentions a selector I gave in a comment at one point before I realised you were trying to use the selectors I provided on the wrong page.

Comment: Sorry @QHarr I mixed the two in the comment using the original code I got the following:  email <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '[href*=mail]')
> name
[1] "remoteDriver fields"
$remoteServerAddr
[1] "localhost"

$port
[1] 4545

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$javascript
[1] TRUE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$extraCapabilities
list()

[1] "webElement fields"
$elementId
[1] "763164ab-0f04-46ff-bb92-815179fd39e5"

Comment: so it found it yes?

Comment: yep I solved it. It was a weird object to me since it does not retur a list as I expected, Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I get around it by using rvest in the following way in the loop

```
 #use Rselenium to dowload emails
  rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
  remDr <- rD[["client"]]
   emails<-list()

  for (i in 1:length(links)) {
    #r<- read_html(link[i])
    remDr$navigate(links[i])
    webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '.abstand_search + [value="Suche starten"]')  # this matches for the element which is interactable
    webElem$clickElement()
    
    r <- read_html(unlist(webElem$getCurrentUrl()))
    mail <- r %>%
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      html_attrs() %>%
      as.character() %>%
      str_subset("mailto:") %>%
      str_remove("mailto:")
    if(length(mail)!=0){
    a<-  str_split(mail, "href")
    a<-unlist(a)
    w<-which((grepl("@",a, fixed = T)))
    emails<-c(emails,a[w])
    }else{    emails<-c(emails,NA)}
    rm(mail)
    
  }
```

Not than elegant code but it works. For names is more complex and I cannot find a way to get the right css or xpath. Let me know if you can think of a more elegant and fast code or if the issue can only be soleved using a brute forze way.